# Result : IdTokenResult(Instance of 'PlatformIdTokenResult')

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am authenticating using the phone number and I am trying to get IdToken, but instead, I am getting an instance of PlatFormTokenResult. Where am I wrong?

```
final FirebaseUser user =
    ( await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
currentUser.getIdToken().then((id){
  print(  id.toString());
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the `token` property from the result of `getIdToken()` which returns an instance of `PlatformTokenResult` as shown.

So instead of

```
print(id.toString());
```

You should use:

```
print(id.token.toString());
```